# ORA-02270 - can FK in Oracle be defined on VARCHAR2 column?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

SQL is more than words:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "currency" ("id" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
> "currency" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
> "name" VARCHAR2(1020) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY("id"));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "user" ("id" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
> "name" VARCHAR2(1020) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
> "currency" VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY("id"));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_6956883FFF467AE9 ON "currency" ("currency");
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE "user" ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8D93D6496956883F6956883F695
> FOREIGN KEY ("currency") REFERENCES "currency" ("currency");
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> ```

[repro on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7de31287a57c063b3304987b06f76137)

The column types are the same and unique index is added.

Why the FK cannot be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique index does not include a unique constraint.

Add the constraint and try again:

```
alter table "currency" add unique("currency") using index IDX_6956883FFF467AE9;
```

Comment: Yes - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9e9cf8e0d58247e86dae439ebde578c thank you